# Ansible - Role Argument Validation Dict

Tags: validation, ansible

I started using the role argument validation which was introduced in Ansible 2.11. For example an easy variable of type string looks like this in meta/argument_specs.yml:

```yaml
argument_specs:
  main:
    short_description: "Checking firewall global policies"
    options:
      openwrt_firewall_default_forward:
        type: "str"
        choices:
          - "ACCEPT"
          - "REJECT"
          - "DROP"
```

But I have more complex variables than that, for example dicts. This is what the variables can look like:

```yaml
openwrt_firewall_zoneshost:
  MGMT:
    forward: "REJECT"
    input: "ACCEPT"
    output: "ACCEPT"
      #log: 1
    interfaces:
      - "mgmt"
  SECURE:
    forward: "ACCEPT"
    input: "ACCEPT"
    output: "ACCEPT"
      #log: 1
    interfaces:
      - "secure"
```

or like this:

```yaml
openwrt_firewall_ruleshost:
  "syslog logrx1":
    src: "*"
    dest: "RXFORELLE"
    dest_ip:
      - "{{ hostvars['alsomyhost.mydomain.de']['primary_ip6'] }}"
    dest_port: "514"
    target: "ACCEPT"
  "MGMT myhost":
    src: "MGMT"
    dest: "RXFORELLE"
    dest_ip:
      - "{{ hostvars['myhost.mydomain.de']['primary_ip6'] }}"
    proto: "tcp"
    dest_port: "22"
    target: "ACCEPT"
```

I would like to be able to validate those, meaning. Some of the attributes are mandatory like `src` or `destination`. Some others are optional, but if given I would like to make sure they are of the correct type.

Honestly I don't understand the documentation with reference to this very problem having dict variables. Could someone please outline what the validation structure would look like for those type of variables.

Reference:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-argument-validation

Comment: See this question on Codidact: https://software.codidact.com/posts/289946

Answer (score 1):

You can repeat `options:` in the definition of an option, these are sometimes called "suboptions", and within there you can use all the same fields to define what that dict should contain.

```yaml
argument_specs:
  main:
    short_description: "Checking firewall global policies"
    options:
      openwrt_firewall_ruleshost:
        type: "dict"
        required: true
        options:
          src:
            required: true
            type: str
```

Comment: Well should't be the string on the second options level be for example "syslog logrx1" instead of "src"?
In the IRC channel I was told to do so. Since my key names vary and are unpredictable I was told that with this very method I cannot validate my arguments at all.

Comment: @imp1sh I was there in the channel, I posted this answer before it was revealed that your key names were variable. But if you want to do suboption validation in an argspec, this is the way to do that. As for the key name, yes I misread your original post and didn't notice that key.